# Querying the values from a Picklist

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to query the values from the different Picklist in Opportunity. I don't want to query the actual Opportunity, just the values from the Picklist. So if I have a Picklist called Source and it has the values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want to query the picklist and get back those values. Is this possible? If so, how in the world do you do it? Thanks!

Comment: Using js or c#? If js, is the code already running on the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
request.EntityLogicalName = "opportunity";
request.LogicalName = "new_businessunit";

RetrieveAttributeResponse response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)orgService.Execute(request);
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklist = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;

int? businessid = null;

foreach (OptionMetadata option in picklist.OptionSet.Options)
{
     string businesslabel = option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString();
}
```